# Systemd service supposed to run on shutdown does not execute bash script

Tags: systemd

bash script is in /opt/CleanUp.sh

```
find /home/*/Downloads/* -type f -exec shred -uz {} \;
rm -r /home/*/Downloads/*
find /home/*/Documents/* -type f -exec shred -uz {} \;
rm -r /home/*/Documents/*
find /home/*/Pictures/* -type f -exec shred -uz {} \;
rm -r /home/*/Pictures/*
find /home/*/Videos/* -type f -exec shred -uz {} \;
rm -r /home/*/Videos/*
find /home/*/Music/* -type f -exec shred -uz {} \;
rm -r /home/*/Music/*
exit 0
```

.service file in /etc/systemd/system/CleanUp.service

```
[Unit]
Description=CleanUp Service
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=halt.target shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart= /opt/CleanUp.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target shutdown.target reboot.target
```

The script does not execute on shutdown. When I try to start it via

`sudo service CleanUp start`

I get this error

```
× CleanUp.service - CleanUp Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/CleanUp.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since *****************; 7s ago
    Process: 21217 ExecStart=/opt/CleanUp.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 21217 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 1ms

*********** *hostname* systemd[1]: Starting CleanUp.service - CleanUp Service...
*********** *hostname* (eanUp.sh)[21217]: CleanUp.service: Failed to locate executable /opt/CleanUp.sh: Permission denied
*********** *hostname* (eanUp.sh)[21217]: CleanUp.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/CleanUp.sh: Permission denied
********** *hostname* systemd[1]: CleanUp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
********** *hostname* systemd[1]: CleanUp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
********** *hostname* systemd[1]: Failed to start CleanUp.service - CleanUp Service.
```

System info:
Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition) x86_64
Kernel: 6.2.9-200.fc37.x86_64
DE: GNOME 43.4

Comment: What are the permissions on the script? And are you sure it is being executed by `bash` since it does not have a shebang? You might also take out the space after the equals sign for ExecStart.

Comment: The shebang is there, just didn't copy it. Removed space- still doesn't work. Permissions: -rw-r--r--  root root for CleanUp.service;
-rwxr-xr-x root admin  for CleanUp.sh.

Comment: Does the script possibly have `CRLF` line endings? Does `journalctl -u CleanUp` give any extra info?

Comment: No CRLF line endings. cat -A returns only $ line endings. No extra info in journal. Just the 203/EXEC error.

Comment: Solved the problem. Just created a new .sh file as root and pasted the content. Works like a charm. I think the problem was that I incorrectly set file ownership after moving the script to /opt. Ty for your input.